# Find WIFI State in JAVA

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, wifi

In my java application, I want to see what state the wifi is at (E.G. 1 bar, 2 bar or no wifi)

I was wondering how I would be able to find the wifi state of the computer in native Java, or by using a ping/pong application or if I have to parse the state of the wifi directly to the application

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

P.S. I'm not using android

Comment: First of all, my questions for you are: 

What have you tried to solve it?
Can we see your code?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you get an answer here, you can't assume that WiFi signal will necessarily mean that your REST/service calls will succeed.  They may still fail.

Comment: I don't have any code right now as I don't know how I would do this is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cover the Windows platform then you can utilize a little method like this:

```
public int getWirelessStrength() {
    // The returned integer value is in relation to strength percent.
    // If 75 is returned then the wireless signal strength is at 75%.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int signalStrength = 0;
    String cmd = "netsh wlan show interfaces"; 
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
        if (p.isAlive()) { p.destroy(); }

        // Get the Signal Strength.
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("signal")) {
                String[] ss = list.get(i).split(":");
                if(ss.length == 2) {
                    signalStrength = Integer.parseInt(ss[1].replace("%","").trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) { 
        Logger.getLogger("getWirelessStrength()").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return signalStrength;
}
```

The above method utilizes the Windows [**Netsh** Command-line Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts) to acquire the desired information. The returned integer result is a percent of signal strength so, if 75 is returned then the WiFi signal strength is 75%. If you want to do something similar for Unix or Linux then you can use the [**iwlist**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist) or [**iwconfig**](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-iwconfig/) command and parse out the required signal strength in a similar fashion. For the MAC I believe you would need to use the [**Airport Utility**](http://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!